# Archiving Log Files

Tags: c#, .net, logging, service, locking

I have just rewritten a windows service  process that outputs important info debug to a log file in the /programdata/myservice/ folder.

However at night at midnight I have a job that is supposed to take the current days log file and remove it's contents and then create an archived logfile with the date in the name for 3 days e.g LogfileArchived15092014.log.

Some code then runs to delete log files older than this date so I only ever have todays current log file and 2 archived ones for debugging older issues etc.

Now I have copied the code that does this from an old service that is working and it archives the log files and deletes old ones. However for some reason when this new job runs I get I/O errors such as this (from the event viewer)

Error Running System Jobs: I/O Error archiving log file: C:\ProgramData\Brainiac\LogfileArchived; The process cannot access the file 'C:\ProgramData\Brainiac\Logfile.log' because it is being used by another process.

Now the reason the first path doesn't have an extension on it e.g C:\ProgramData\Brainiac\LogfileArchived is because it's obviously thrown an error before it's got to the part where the file date is created to be appended to the filename e.g

```
// set a lock up to prevent other processes locking
this.Locked = true;

// wrap in try as it keeps failing!!!!
try
{
    // take contents of current log file - the daily one I have been logging to all day      
    // I guess this is where the error is being raised due to the absence 
    // of a .log extension in the error message when mentioning the filename
    string content = this.ReadFileString(this.logFilePath);

    // for some reason todays log file was empty 
    // why would this be unless loggging was disabled?
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
    {
        // create a new log file with date stamp of yesterday added to the filename and guff removed to make it valid
        string file_date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1).ToString().Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "");

        // remove time part - should be done at midnight but if not ensure colons and spaces are removed
        file_date = file_date.Replace("00:00:00", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(" ", "");

        // append .log to it
        this.logfilearchivepath += file_date + ".log";

        //Append all the contents of my daily log file to this new file 
        File.AppendAllText(this.logfilearchivepath, content, Encoding.UTF8);
```

So I suspect it is bombing out on this line

```
string content = this.ReadFileString(this.logFilePath);
```

Due to no extension being in the error message. So maybe I need a different way of accessing the contents?

Now I don't know what other process has it locked (can I find out somehow?) but I have tried the following.

1. Ensuring I don't have the file open on my own computer.
2. Adding a flag in which is supposed to prevent ANY logging to the log file. As you can see at the top I go

   // set a lock up to prevent other processes locking
   this.Locked = true;

and in my method that does the logging I have a check for it to exit ASAP e.g

```
// log to our application data folder - unless locked for some reason
public void LogMsg(string msg, string debugLevel = "HIGH")
{
   // we are prevented from logging at this point in time
   if (this.Locked) return;
```

3. I also have wrapped the call to the ArchiveLogFile() method in 3 try/catch statements, each with a Thread.Sleep in between of longer and longer gaps in case something was still logging.
4. I have also tried using DB locks.

So I have a table called LOCKS and methods to insert/remove a lock record and also a method to check one doesn't exist.

So if multiple processes tried running the same code at the same time from different apps then it shouldn't be able to as a lock record would exist in the database which gets inserted before the job starts running and is removed after the job has completed (a RUNNING lock)

Also once completed a LOGFILE_ARCHIVED lock record is inserted so that the same OR a different job knows the log file has been archived and doesn't try to archive it again.

I use the computers name in the lock files as the process could run on multiple servers/computers at any one time.

So what other solutions could I do to get round this problem?

Should I use a different method for obtaining the log file contents that wouldn't be blocked by something locking the file (I don't know what is doing the locking but the this.Locked = True should prevent anything being logged to the file during the archive job) but obviously the "lock" on the file is higher up than my code.

This is a windows service written in C# .NET 4.5 on a Win 7 machine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way the function ReadFileString is a static function which is a wrapper for using the StreamReader to read in the contents of the file. It does exist in the project.

Comment: That is when I am running it. After midnight. I am also obtaining a record from a DB that says whether logging is ON/OFF which is set OFF before I try to do anything with the log file in case concurrent processes try to hit the DLL. What can I do to ensure the logfile can be read from the file without the process "locking" it then? By the way I am using exactly the same code as my old job for this archive process and that works a charm every night.There may be a few I/O errors in the event viewer but eventually it gets to do the job and copy the data over.

Comment: At the moment the "logging" method, the one that logs any messages to the file is using File.AppendAllText(LogFilePath, msg, Encoding.UTF8); where msg is the new msg + "\n" to b added to the file. It's in a Try/Catch. Should I use some other method to ensure after I output to the file it's released?

Comment: I also wrap the call to the "Archive" method in 3 try/catches with a thread.sleep of increasing times between them. If after all 3 its still failed to run I try again 5 minutes later.

Comment: Why have you deleted all your comments and answers to my questions under this question? It looks like I was just talking to myself!! I am not crazy someone WAS writing comments here but has removed them!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I just had an issue with the this.Locked being in the Helper class and other concurrent instances of the DLL being called ignoring it (multi threaded issue) so I just placed my DB Lock check into the Init of the Helper Class so it was

```
this.Locked = this.GetCurrentLockedStatus();
```

And then any process would have got the same value. This meant no logging was going on during the file transfer as I was adding the LOCK record in before attempting to do it and exiting any LogMsg method if

```
this.Locked = true;
```

Now it works like a charm. Don't really know why the old service was working though. I can see lots of I/O errors in the event log for it but eventually it just manages to do it for some reason. This method of using the DB to maintain locks seems to be much better and faster.

Thanks for your help.